# difference between spy and direct object

Tags: java, testing, mockito

As far as i have gathered knowledge on Mockito, when we spy an object and call any method on it then its real implementation is executed.

```
class Abc {
    public int fun() {
         //to do stuff
         return 5;
    }
}
```

Test Using spy:

```
Class AbcTest {
    public void testFun()
    {
        Abc ob= spy(Abc.class);
        ob.fun();   //calls real implementation
        //Other stuff
    }
}
```

Test Without spy:

```
Class AbcTest
{
    public void testFun() {
         Abc ob=new Abc();
         ob.fun();
         //other stuff
    }
}
```

What is the difference b/w calling the real implementation of a method using above two methods??

Comment: I read following in Mockito docs. "Mockito does not delegate calls to the passed real instance, instead it actually creates a copy of it." Does this statement mean that when i call fun() by spying Abc class, then Mockito create a copy of the fun() method and executes it?? If yes, then what is the benefit of doing this? I mean , why take an overhead to create a copy, when u have a real implementation available..

Answer (score 3):

Using a spy should result in the same behavior in the system under test, but with the advantage of overriding and verifying method behavior if you'd like.

```
class AbcTest {
  public void testFun()
  {
    Abc ob= spy(Abc.class);
    ob.fun();   //calls real implementation
    //Other stuff
  }
}
```

This (quoted from your question) won't compile as such; you need to `spy(new Abc())` instead of `spy(Abc.class)`. It's a subtle point, but it's actually really important to knowing what's going on.

---

Consider this:

```
Abc nonSpy = new Abc();
Abc isASpy = Mockito.spy(nonSpy);
```

At this point, `isASpy` is not the same object as `nonSpy`; it's an object that records the interactions and forwards to [a copy of the original object `nonSpy`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13)—unless you've stubbed it using `doReturn` or `doThrow` (etc), at which point it skips the call to the original method and performs your stubbed action instead.

You can *imagine* that Mockito has written the following implementation for you:

```
class AbcSpy extends Abc {             // simplified analogy of Mockito proxy
  @Override public void fun() {
    recordCallToFun();                 // record for verification later
    if (hasStubbedBehaviorForFun) {
      performStubbedBehaviorForFun();  // perform doReturn/doThrow/etc
      return;
    }
    copyOfOriginalObject.fun();        // call real method
  }
}
```

By passing `isASpy` to your system under test (as opposed to `nonSpy`), you can give your system under test a real object to interact with, and provide a *few* behavior overrides. You can also, of course, use the spy simply to verify that the system under test properly interacted with the collaborator Abc.

Answer (score -1):

@Spy or the spy() method can be used to wrap a real object. Every call, unless specified otherwise, is delegated to the object.

Sometimes it's impossible or impractical to use Mockito.when(Object) for stubbing spies. Therefore for spies it is recommended to always use doReturn|Answer|Throw()|CallRealMethod family of methods for stubbing. Example:

```
List list = new LinkedList();
List spy = spy(list);

//Impossible: real method is called so spy.get(0) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException (the list is yet empty)
when(spy.get(0)).thenReturn("foo");

//You have to use doReturn() for stubbing
doReturn("foo").when(spy).get(0);
```

Mockito *does not* delegate calls to the passed real instance, instead it actually creates a copy of it. So if you keep the real instance and interact with it, don't expect the spied to be aware of those interaction and their effect on real instance state. The corollary is that when an *unstubbed* method is called *on the spy* but *not on the real instance*, you won't see any effects on the real instance.

Comment: i have gone through these docs.. Couldn't understand obviously so asked a question .